# Payload's value is null in PostgreSQL delete events

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm using Debezium and Kafka connect to get PostgreSQL's change events. `UPDATE` and `CREATE` events work fine but the payload's value is `NULL` when I delete something from a table:

```
{
  topic: 'omnichannel.public.Department',
  partition: 0,
  message: {
    magicByte: 2,
    attributes: 0,
    timestamp: '1668117212311',
    offset: '12',
    key: Buffer(272) [Uint8Array] [
      123,  34, 115,  99, 104, 101, 109,  97,  34,  58, 123,  34,
      116, 121, 112, 101,  34,  58,  34, 115, 116, 114, 117,  99,
      116,  34,  44,  34, 102, 105, 101, 108, 100, 115,  34,  58,
       91, 123,  34, 116, 121, 112, 101,  34,  58,  34, 115, 116,
      114, 105, 110, 103,  34,  44,  34, 111, 112, 116, 105, 111,
      110,  97, 108,  34,  58, 102,  97, 108, 115, 101,  44,  34,
      102, 105, 101, 108, 100,  34,  58,  34, 110,  97, 109, 101,
      115, 112,  97,  99, 101,  73, 100,  34, 125,  44, 123,  34,
      116, 121, 112, 101,
      ... 172 more items
    ],
    value: null,
    headers: {},
    isControlRecord: false,
    batchContext: {
      firstOffset: '11',
      firstTimestamp: '1668117212311',
      partitionLeaderEpoch: 0,
      inTransaction: false,
      isControlBatch: false,
      lastOffsetDelta: 1,
      producerId: '-1',
      producerEpoch: -1,
      firstSequence: -1,
      maxTimestamp: '1668117212311',
      timestampType: 0,
      magicByte: 2
    }
  },
  heartbeat: [Function: heartbeat],
  pause: [Function: pause]
}
```

Comment: 1. Are you getting both before and after values in case of UPDATE events? If not, set REPLICA IDENTITY to FULL.   
2. Debezium publishes an extra tombstone record in case of DELETE events. By any chance, are we looking at the tombstone record here.

Comment: Yes, you were right, It's the tombstone event. The problem was PostgreSQL version because the version 15 is not supported by Debezium 2 but fortunately they release alpha version of Debezium 2.1 yesterday which now supports PostgreSQL 15

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that PostgreSQL 15 is not supported in Debezium, Using Debezium 2.1 fixed the problem.